# How can I retrieve border-radius by using ref of React?

Tags: reactjs, get, border, ref, border-radius

```
ref.current.style.borderRadius
```

it's not working.

I expect it return the current border radius of the referred element. **your text**

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? Did you get an error message? Did your computer catch on fire?

Comment: my element has its border radius but i can't retrieve by ref. `ref.current.style.borderRadius ` it's give me empty string.